# How can I delete duplicates group 3 columns using two criteria (first two columns)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, duplicates

That is my data set `enter code here`

```
Year created  Week created  SUM_New  SUM_Closed  SUM_Open
0          2018             1       17           0        82
1          2018             6       62          47        18
2          2018             6       62          47        18
3          2018             6       62          47        18
4          2018             6       62          47        18
```

In last three columns there is already the sum for the year and week. I need to get rid of duplicates so that the table contains unique values (for the example above):

```
Year created  Week created  SUM_New  SUM_Closed  SUM_Open
0          2018             1       17           0        82
4          2018             6       62          47        18
```

I tried to group data but it somehow works wrong and does what I need but just for one column.

`df.groupby(['Year created', 'Week created']).size()`

And output:

```
Year created  Week created
2017          48               2
              49              25
              50              54
              51              36
              52               1
2018          1               17
              2               50
              3               37
```

But it is just one column and I don't know which one because even if I separate the data on three parts and do the same procedure for each part I get the same result (as above) for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Year created', 'Week created'])
print (df)
   Year created  Week created  SUM_New  SUM_Closed  SUM_Open
0          2018             1       17           0        82
1          2018             6       62          47        18
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(['Year created', 'Week created', 'SUM_New', 'SUM_Closed'])
print(df2)
```

hope this helps.